# Running jre keytool results in the Permission Denied error

Tags: java, linux, keytool, rhel7

I have a script running the command:

```
/tmp/jre1.8.0_131/bin/keytool -import -trustcacerts -file '/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/company.crt' -keystore '/tmp/jre1.8.0_131/lib/security/cacerts' -storepass changeit
```

Got the error:

```
bash: /tmp/jre1.8.0_131/bin/keytool: Permission denied
```

Checked all permission on the directories and keytool – all are executable.

I am at RHEL-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of Distributions do not allow files to be executed from within the */tmp* directory.

Either move the jre out of */tmp* (why is it even in there?) or make it executable via:

> sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmp